# Removing superfluous tables with a synchronization?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I'm using SQL Server 2008 r2's replication functionality to update my subscriber database through a transactional pull subscription.  When I mark it for reinitialization, it does fix the schema and data of any modified local tables that exist in the publication snapshot, but it doesn't remove any new tables (and presumably SPs, triggers, etc.) that have been added.  Is there any way to get the synchronization to remove superfluous objects like tables that don't exist in the publication shapshot, in addition to updating and adding existing objects?

Comment: sounds to me like what you need is to logship with a method in between where you restore the logship (so you can interact with it) and then switch back to the logship...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this using native functionality as replication doesn't know about the additional objects so it can't remove them.